# Optimize this query please

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle10g, query-optimization

```
SELECT
      B.CE_ID,
      A.PPL_CNTR_ID,
      SUM ( A.NBR_IN ) ENTERS,
      SUM ( A.NBR_OUT ) EXITS,
      A.LOG_TS
      + DECODE ( TO_CHAR ( A.LOG_TS,
                       'mi' ),
               '05', 55
                    / 1440,
               '10', 50
                    / 1440,
               '15', 45
                    / 1440,
               '20', 40
                    / 1440,
               '25', 35
                    / 1440,
               '30', 30
                    / 1440,
               '35', 25
                    / 1440,
               '40', 20
                    / 1440,
               '45', 15
                    / 1440,
               '50', 10
                    / 1440,
               '55', 5
                    / 1440,
               0 )
          TS
FROM
      OUTPUTDB.TPPL_CNTR_TRAFFIC A,
      FLUX.V_CE_PPLCNTR B
WHERE
         A.LOG_TS BETWEEN '07-Sep-13' AND '08-Sep-13'
      AND A.PPL_CNTR_ID = B.PPL_CNTR_ID
      AND B.CE_ID IN (SELECT
                        DISTINCT CE_DPN_ID
                   FROM
                        TCE_RLT
                   START WITH
                        CE_PRN_ID = 5798
                   CONNECT BY
                        PRIOR CE_DPN_ID = CE_PRN_ID)
GROUP BY
      B.CE_ID,
      A.PPL_CNTR_ID,
      A.LOG_TS
      + DECODE ( TO_CHAR ( A.LOG_TS,
                       'mi' ),
               '05', 55
                    / 1440,
               '10', 50
                    / 1440,
               '15', 45
                    / 1440,
               '20', 40
                    / 1440,
               '25', 35
                    / 1440,
               '30', 30
                    / 1440,
               '35', 25
                    / 1440,
               '40', 20
                    / 1440,
               '45', 15
                    / 1440,
               '50', 10
                    / 1440,
               '55', 5
                    / 1440,
               0 )
ORDER BY
      B.CE_ID,
      A.PPL_CNTR_ID,
      A.LOG_TS
      + DECODE ( TO_CHAR ( A.LOG_TS,
                       'mi' ),
               '05', 55
                    / 1440,
               '10', 50
                    / 1440,
               '15', 45
                    / 1440,
               '20', 40
                    / 1440,
               '25', 35
                    / 1440,
               '30', 30
                    / 1440,
               '35', 25
                    / 1440,
               '40', 20
                    / 1440,
               '45', 15
                    / 1440,
               '50', 10
                    / 1440,
               '55', 5
                    / 1440,
               0 )
```

The inner subquery

```
                   SELECT
                        DISTINCT CE_DPN_ID
                   FROM
                        TCE_RLT
                   START WITH
                        CE_PRN_ID = 5798
                   CONNECT BY
                        PRIOR CE_DPN_ID = CE_PRN_ID
```

returns 970  rows , But it's taking very long time to execute , Please suggest any alternate clause or joining so that It runs faster . The 2 tables used have only one column in common , So I am pretty sure no cross joining is taking place .

Comment: Please format your question. Can you add execution plans?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but this condition: `where a.log_ts between '07-Sep-13' and '08-Sep-13'` relies on implicit data type conversion (which is a very bad thing) and will fail miserably when run from a client using different NLS settings

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use  A.LOG_TS BETWEEN '07-Sep-13' AND '08-Sep-13' rather use  TO_DATE( '07-09-13' , 'DD-MM-YY')
2. Replace DISTINCT query if possible
3. Remove sorting i.e. order by

Comment: Using TO_DATE() is certainly good advice - using TO_DATE(.., 'MON') is not, since this *also* relies on certain NLS settings. Use TO_DATE(..., 'MM') instead.

Comment: I agree with Frank. `MON` would fail for October on my computer.

Comment: Yes. I also agree MM is the best

Comment: NB You can also specify dates using the shorter date-literal syntax as `DATE '2013-09-08'`.

Comment: Since you use SELECT DISTINCT in an IN predicate rather than to produce results, you can simply omit DISTINCT and you'll get the same correct behaviour (duplicate rows have no effect). Of course, duplicate results in a CONNECT BY tree query are impossible in practice to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
 A.LOG_TS
  + DECODE ( TO_CHAR ( A.LOG_TS,
                   'mi' ),
           '05', 55
                / 1440,
           '10', 50
                / 1440,
           '15', 45
                / 1440,
           '20', 40
                / 1440,
           '25', 35
                / 1440,
           '30', 30
                / 1440,
           '35', 25
                / 1440,
           '40', 20
                / 1440,
           '45', 15
                / 1440,
           '50', 10
                / 1440,
           '55', 5
                / 1440,
           0 )
```

Horrible, use a proper conversion for A.LOG_TS in the result (e.g. SELECT TO_CHAR(A.LOG_TS, 'YYYYMMDDHHMI') TS or any other format, without using default conversions) and use A.LOG_TS itself without pointless conversions in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 1):

```
                 SELECT
                    DISTINCT CE_DPN_ID
               FROM
                    TCE_RLT
               START WITH
                    CE_PRN_ID = 5798
               CONNECT BY
                    PRIOR CE_DPN_ID = CE_PRN_ID
```

If you can add a column to TCE_RLT, the "root" ID, furnished with an index, would make the query cheaper:

```
SELECT CE_DPN_ID
FROM TCE_RLT
WHERE ROOT_ID = 5798
```

Such a field could be computed cheaply on insert:

```
INSERT INTO TCE_RLT (CE_DPN_ID, CE_PRN_ID,ROOT_ID) 
    VALUES 5798,5798,5798;
INSERT INTO TCE_RLT (CE_DPN_ID, CE_PRN_ID,ROOT_ID) 
    SELECT 12,34,ROOT_ID FROM TCE_RLT WHERE CE_DPN_ID = 34;
```